# ODE crash on a simple scenario on ignition gazebo

Tags: gazebo-ignition, gazebo-edifice

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello !

I'm trying to run a simple scenario with ignition where there are multiple spheres falling on the ground and colliding with each other but after a little time (it seems there are too much collisions) ignition crash and I have the message :

```
ODE INTERNAL ERROR 1: assertion "aabbBound >= dMinIntExact && aabbBound < dMaxIntExact" failed in collide() [collision_space.cpp:460]
```

I tested with different versions of ignition (citadel, dome, edifice) with ubuntu 20.04 but I just get the same error and I also can't find the file **collision_space.cpp**.

Does anyone have such problem? Any solutions? Or maybe ignition can't support this type of simulation ?

My world looks like this :

```
<sdf version="1.7">
<world name="4">
    <physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
              <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
              <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
    </physics>
    <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
    <include>
        <uri>model://floor_r1_i1</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i1</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i2</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i3</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i4</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i5</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i6</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i7</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i8</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i9</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i10</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i11</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i12</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i13</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i14</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i15</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i16</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i17</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i18</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i19</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i20</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i21</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i22</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i23</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i24</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i25</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i26</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i27</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i28</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i29</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://sphere_r4_i30</uri>
    </include>
</world>
```

And sphere object is :

```
 <model name="sphere_r4_i1">
  <link name="sphere_link">
    <inertial>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.1</ixx>
        <ixy>0</ixy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.1</iyy>
        <iyz>0</iyz>
        <izz>0.1</izz>
      </inertia>
      <mass>1.0</mass>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="sphere_collision">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.02</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual name="sphere_visual">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.02</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <ambient>0 0 1 1</ambient>
        <diffuse>0 0 1 1</diffuse>
        <specular>0 0 1 1</specular>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <pose> insert different pose here </pose>
</model>
```

With different pose for each

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27052/ode-crash-on-a-simple-scenario-on-ignition-gazebo/) by [Defim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48524/defim/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2021-06-16**:
could you please attach the world you are using to generate the error?

**Comment by [Defim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48524/defim/) on 2021-06-18**:
I added the world I am using in the question

**Comment by [Defim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48524/defim/) on 2021-06-21**:
Thank you for your answer I think this is indeed the same problem but (I'm sorry I'm a beginner) I don't know how to install the repository dart to be used by ignition

**Comment by [AndrejOrsula](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44778/andrejorsula/) on 2021-06-23**:
One way is to remove you current DART version (e.g. `sudo apt-get remove libdart*`) and then build/install the fork from source (link to instructions is in README of the repository). If your Ignition uses a different version of DART, then you need to also build Ignition from source (instruction are on http://ignitionrobotics.org) while specifying the correct version of the DART in CMakeLists.txt of ign-physics.
I am not sure, but there might be an easier solution if the binaries are available.

**Comment by [Defim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48524/defim/) on 2021-06-23**:
Thank you it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This might be related to https://github.com/ignition-forks/dart/pull/6. Using the [fork](https://github.com/ignition-forks/dart) fixed such issue for me, but it is only really a problem in worlds with way too many objects.

[Not related to this issue] For anyone getting the same error, it can also occur if you let objects fall forever into the abyss. If that is the case, consider adding an invisible collision plane under your world.

---

Originally posted by [AndrejOrsula](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44778/andrejorsula/) with karma: 101 on 2021-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1